# Why does my java program skip my input and hang on the IF statements?

Tags: java

Everything else in my program works except for this single method, where it skips the sc.next() and then hangs on my if's.

```
public static String getChoice() {
    boolean choiceSelector = false;

    // construct a Scanner object for getting input
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? Y/N");
    String choice = " ";

    do{
    choice = sc.next();

    if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
        choice="Y";
        choiceSelector = true;
    }
    if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
        choice="N";
        choiceSelector = true;
    } else
        choice = sc.next("Please enter a correct value.");

    } while(choiceSelector == false);

    return choice;
}//end getChoice
```

Comment: What is the method you call before this one? Please show it as well.

Comment: I'm calling this method from the main method, the main method works perfectly, this method only determines whether or not the main method's while loop should continue or terminate.

Comment: No it doesn't. It blocks in `next()`. NB `next()` doesn't print a prompt. You are misusing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly put another `else`, since you anyway ask them for a proper value even when the input is `Y` at first as well :

```
if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
    choice="Y";
    choiceSelector = true;
} else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))...
```

---

and break

```
choice = sc.next("Please enter a correct value."); // not a valid pattern provided as an input here
```

as

```
System.out.println("Please enter a correct value.");
choice = sc.next();
```

---

and

```
return choiceSelector; // the boolean value
```

Comment: @user6831363 Do accept it as an answer for references if it did help. :)